# Cannot test Api after deploying to heroku

Tags: node.js, mongodb, api, heroku, postman

After deploying my app to heroku, I can't make a get or post request on postman using the deployed app url `https://blue-collar-backend.herokuapp.com` .If I try to test on postman using the url, I get this error

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
</head>

<body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /user/signup</pre>
</body>

</html>
```

And this is my deployed app link [here](https://blue-collar-backend.herokuapp.com). But I can only make a get request to the main server `https://blue-collar-backend.herokuapp.com/`. I don't know if there's something I am supposed to add to my code. Also, my app is already connected to a mongo atlas database

This is my route.js file:

```
const express = require("express");

const userRoute = express.Router();
const UserController = require("../controllers/user/user.controller");


userRoute.post("/signup", UserController.signup)
userRoute.get("/verify/:emailToken", UserController.verify)

userRoute.post("/login", UserController.login);

module.exports = userRoute
```

And my index.js file:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const env = require("dotenv");

const connectDatabase = require("./config/db");
const userRoute = require("./routes/user.route")

env.config()
connectDatabase()

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;

const app = express()

app.disable('x-powered-by');

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,HEAD,OPTIONS',
  );
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept',
  );

  return next();
});

app.get('/', (req, res) =>
  res.status(200).json({
    error: false,
    message: 'Blue Collar server is ready to move',
  }),
);

app.use("/user", userRoute);

const SERVER = app.listen(PORT, () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    console.info(
      `listening on http://localhost:${
        SERVER.address().port
      } @ ${new Date().toJSON()}`,
    );
  }
});

module.exports = SERVER;
```

Comment: Looks like you don't have a route handler for `POST /user/signup`. Can you share the relevant backend code?

Comment: Thank you for your response.I just edited the post by adding the relevant backend code. I would be willing to showcase any other relevant part of my code.

Answer (score 0):

This might sound stupid but the reason as to why none of the requests were found was because I hadn't pushed my new updates to github(me believing I did and not checking) since I set an automatic deploy to heroku. lol. Thank you so much Arun for yor concern and help